# web2py Custom User Profile?

Tags: web2py, profile

> What is the 'correct' way to extend the base `auth_user` table/the
>   whole `auth` system in order to support a number of custom user
>   profile fields (such as username, location, birthday, etc.)?

I've caught glances of approaches from Googling, but no one ever seems to give a straight answer. The answer seems to be either completely replacing the base `auth_user` table with a custom one (and letting the auth system know), or creating a new extension table with a foreign key reference back to the base `auth_user` table. The first seems to have reusability problems, the second is going to have problems with forms and such.

Does anyone have any pointers to patch in something as universal as custom user profiles without breaking too much?

**EDIT:** A bit more reading suggests overriding the base `auth_user` table is the way to go, and after some trial and error, I've found it's as easy as dropping in a block of code:

```
# before define_tables()
auth.settings.table_user = db.define_table('auth_user',
    Field('email', length=128,label=T('Email'), default='', unique=True),
    Field('user_name', length=128, label=T('User name'), default='', unique=True, 
        requires=IS_NOT_IN_DB(db, 'auth_user.user_name')
    ),
    Field('password', 'password', readable=False, label=T('Password'),
        requires=CRYPT()
    ),
    Field('first_name', length=128, label=T('First name'), default='',
        requires=(IS_NOT_EMPTY(error_message=auth.messages.is_empty),
        IS_NOT_IN_DB(db, 'auth_user.first_name'))
    ),
    Field('last_name', length=128, label=T('Last name'), default='',
        requires=(IS_NOT_EMPTY(error_message=auth.messages.is_empty),
        IS_NOT_IN_DB(db, 'auth_user.last_name'))
    ),
    Field('registration_key', length=128, default='', writable=False, readable=False),
    Field('country', 'string', length=15, label=T('Country'),
        requires=IS_NULL_OR(IS_IN_SET(('England')))
    ),
)
```

So long as this gets executed after `auth = Auth(db)` and before `auth.define_tables()` in models/db.py, it all seems to work out okay. The fields show up on the user profile page, and everything else still works as expected.

Not sure how to answer my own question, so in the meantime, if someone could explain *why* this is the right way to do it, and what else must be kept in mind, I'd appreciate it!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`auth.settings.table_user_name` stores the name of the user table (which defaults to `auth_user`), and `auth.settings.table_user` is a reference to the user table itself. Those two settings are used elsewhere in the Auth code, so that's why it is important to update them when you create a custom user table (in your case, you don't need to update `auth.settings.table_user_name` because you kept the default name). There is a section in the book demonstrating this method of [customizing Auth tables](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/9#Customizing-Auth).

Note, if you just want to add some extra fields to the default `auth_user` table, instead of redefining the entire table as you have done, you can simply do:

```
auth.settings.extra_fields[auth.settings.table_user_name] = [Field('myfield1',...),
    Field('myfield2',...), etc.]
```

before calling `auth.define_tables()`, and those extra fields will be appended to the `auth_user` table. Note, if there are some fields in the default `auth_user` table that you simply don't want to use, you can hide them in registration and profile forms by setting their `readable` and `writable` attributes to `False`.

Comment: Thanks, Anthony! You're right, there is some official documentation there, and your solution is better than mine. It all seems to fit nicely. One extra thing I noticed was that when I defined my custom table with a `username` field, username was used for login instead of `email`. This is what I wanted, and the book says it's built-in behaviour, which is extra nice! Thanks for clearing all that up.

Comment: No problem. Note, if you want to change the label for the `username` field in the Auth forms, you can specify the label via `auth.messages.label_username` (it defaults to "Username").